# Extract strings with multiple words in Postgres 11.0

Tags: postgresql

I have following column in Postgres table. I would like to only get values where there are multiple words in a string.

```
col1
nilotinib hydrochloride
ergamisol
ergamisol
methdilazine hydrochloride
```

The desired output is

```
col1
nilotinib hydrochloride
methdilazine hydrochloride
```

I am using following pattern to extract the strings but it's not working

```
SELECT regexp_match(col1, '^\w+\s+.*') from tb1;
```

Comment: Can you show us the full SQL query that you're using, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To filter rows, use a `WHERE` clause in your statement:

```
SELECT col1
FROM tb1
WHERE col1 ~ '^\w+\s+.*';
```

See [the string matching documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html) for alternatives to your pattern. For your case, `col1 ~ '\s'` should be sufficient, or `col1 SIMILAR TO '%[[:space:]]%'`.